# Unkown string showing up on rendered HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

A random string "b b b b b" gets inserted between two HTML components which doesn't exist in my code to begin with. I currently have a js script to find this garbage string and just remove it manually. Was wondering if anyone knew why this was happening so I could actually fix it instead of this workaround

This is how the relevant part of the code looks on my local machine (look at the start of the table tag) -

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-1"></div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <div class="row answers">
                  <table class="part2">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1. {{form.question_1.label_tag}}</td>
                        {% for choice in form.question_1 %}
                        <td><span class="radio">{{ choice.tag }}</span></td>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </tr>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
```

This is how the rendered HTML Code looks. I copied this from the browser inspect element (Notice how the random b \n b \n b\n is inserted right before the table tag without it being in the code)-

```
<div class="row answers">
                  b
                        
                        b
                        
                        b
                        
                        b
                        
                        b
                        
                        b
                        
                      <table class="part2">

                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1. <label>When this student is feeling happy, they can control their happiness.</label></td>                  
                      </tr>
                      
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

              </div>
```

This is a Python-Django project being run on Chrome. I tested the same with firefox and this string shows up there too. So, I doubt it's a browser issue.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I pretty sure that problem is somewhere in your code that you didn't share here. Also `b b b` may be added by javascript at front side. I recommend to check full flow before page will be displayed

Comment: As @rzlvmp noted, the error is not in your html.  It could even be in your css.  You need to show the js file and the css file, or if these are in your html, then show the full html page.